# Testing my REST interface

Tags: database, rest, junit, mocking, jersey

I'm new to testing and this is case:

1. 1 have a REST service, so a REST.class
2. I have a backend which connects to the DB and persists all the GET/POST method (say 10-15 tables are modified)
3. I have a class in between both, which does the manipulation of the input/output

What I have done so far:
 1. Mocked the classes and the input/output objects of the manip class. This has worked well.
 2. Tested the REST using Jersey Test with my h2 db as test db.

My Q: How can I test the individual parts of the application without any dependency on the DB?
As in, I want to eliminated the actual writing/reading to the test DB and mock that too. Is that possible? these are the basic cases I would like to test:

1. Test if the DB is up i.e. if I can connect to it in the first place.
2. If yes, then check if the tables are properly written into. Right now, i'm checking manually against the DB. I want to eliminate the DB part by mocking.

please let me know if I haven't been clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a test database such as: Apache Derby (JavaDB), Hypersonic, H2, HSQLDB...

Here you can find more details on integration testing with file or in-memory persiste: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/integrationtesting-487452.html